# Rails: Problem with routes and special Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for this question but I can't find my error!
In my Project I have my model called "team".
A User can create a "team" or a "contest". The difference between this both is, that contest requires more data than a normal team.
So I created the columns in my team table.
Well... I also created a new view called create_contest.html.erb :

```
<h1>New team content</h1>

<% form_for @team, :url => { :action => 'create_content' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_fiels :url %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :contact_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_fiels :contact_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In my teams_controller, I created following functions:

```
  def new_contest
  end

  def create_contest
    if @can_create

      @team = Team.new(params[:team])
      @team.user_id = current_user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        if @team.save
          format.html { redirect_to(@team, :notice => 'Contest was successfully created.') }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_back_or_default('/')
    end
  end
```

Now, I want on my teams/new.html.erb a link to "new_contest.html.erb".
So I did:

```
<%= link_to 'click here for new contest!', new_contest_team_path %>
```

When I go to the /teams/new.html.erb page, I get following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_contest_team_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x16fc4f7>
```

So I changed in my routes.rb, `map.resources :teams` to `map.resources :teams, :member=>{:new_contest => :get}`

Now I get following error: `new_contest_team_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"teams", :action=>"new_contest"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["teams", :id, "new_contest"] - are they all satisfied?`

I don't think adding `:member => {...}` is the right way doing this. So, can you tell me what to do? I want to have an URL like /teams/new-contest or something.

My next question: what to do (after fixing the first problem), to validate presentence of all fields for new_contest.html.erb? In my normal new.html.erb, a user does not need all the data. But in new_contest.html.erb he does. Is there a way to make a `validates_presence_of` only for one action (in this case new_contest)?

**UPDATE:** 
Now, I removed my :member part from my routes.rb and wrote:

```
map.new_contest   '/teams/contest/new', :controller => 'teams', :action => 'new_contest'
```

Now, clicking on my link, it redirects me to /teams/contest/new - like I wanted - but I get another error called:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

I think this error is cause of `@team` at `<% form_for @team, :url => { :action => 'create_content_team' } do |f| %>`

What to do for solving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my errors.
For the record:
First of all, I forgot to write the code inside my `def new_contest`. Here it is:

```
  def new_contest
    if @can_create
      @team = Team.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @team }
      end
    else
      redirect_back_or_default('/')
    end
  end
```

There were several typos, too, in my .erb file like text_fiels instead of text_field or create_content instead of create_contest.

current_user is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how your models work, but in my code I've always written;

```
@team.user_id = @current_user.id
```

instead of

```
@team.user_id = current_user.id
```

That would mean the id wasn't being passed to the controller giving you the error, wouldn't it?